# Constrains not working properly in UITableView Cell. How to set it properly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have entered one screenshot here. Actually I am able to see it properly in iPhone 6 Plus screen But when I load it in iPhone 6 it goes out of the screen.

[image]
First Row having text like "Biazzo... " in background there is a view and it's text view. Below that there are 3 labels having in background as a view. And also the button is going out of the screen. How can I make it generic ? Do I need to design separate layout for all screen and putting conditions ? Or constraint can help me to achieve with single layout ? Also getting some extra blank rows. How to remove that also ?

Adding two more images as per my structure.

[image]

[image]

Comment: of course you could do that using a single layout with constraints. post here a screenshot with your current constraints set.

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer your questions one by one:

> How can I make it generic?

You should give your containting view stick to edge constraints, to ensure not going offscreen, and by edge I mean top, leading, bottom & trailing constraints.

> Do I need to design separate layout for all screen and putting
>   conditions?

You don't have to have separate layout for each screen size unless the views are totally different. In your case constraints should be sufficient.

Here's how to set the edge constraints:

1. Select your containing view
2. Add the 4 constraints as shown below, optionally you can "constrain to margins".
3. Make sure that also add constraints to the buttons/labels inside your view.
   Hope that helps.

[image]

Comment: I am trying it and than will inform you. Think that it will work.

Comment: Not getting actual result. Still out of screen. I have updated structure with screenshots. Can you suggest for that. @Abdurrahman